# Xcode Interface builder component moved to some other location?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode10

I have started implementing iOS development with new Xcode 10 and found that Apple Team has just moved the components library to another place. Is there any shortcut/hotkey available for this resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very odd.  `Command-shift-L` now brings up the Library of components.  it's a floating panel that goes away as soon as you drag an item out into your storyboard.

[image: Menu]

[image: palette]

Note if you hold `Option` while dragging out of the palette then the window will remain open.

Comment: Yes found it. Thanks! Option-dragging is something weird that I get to know for adding more components.

Answer (score 0):

Shift-command-L (⇧⌘L) to open the library.

Shift-command-M (⇧⌘M) to open the media library.